# APNS Device Token from Xcode build and App Center build changes only push notifications are received from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, visual-studio-app-center

Facing some issues trying to get push notifications sent to an app downloaded from app center.  I have noticed that the device token being sent to our registration service depending on which build I use (direct build from xcode vs download from appcenter). The deviceToken from the xcode build is able to receive push notifications but nothing comes in from the appcenter build.  Both are using the same p8 certificate and appId.  Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Check if you have configured the production certificate properly inside the apple developer app settings (inside apple account) and inside the Push Notification Sender Party. That what causing you to not receiving notification.
- You might have configured only development certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I believe this might be the issue.  For non-local development on xcode the production certificates will be used correct?  Even though this is technical our UAT environment.  I think this has caused some confusion.

Comment: @djfried Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing similar.